# Does lower stomatal conductance of water influenced by elevated CO2 decrease overall evapotranspiration?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, biophysics, climate-change

From what I understand, elevated CO2 levels [decrease the stomatal conductance of water](https://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/effects-of-rising-atmospheric-concentrations-of-carbon-13254108/) in plants. What I remember from irrigation sciences, higher temperatures should be more demanding on evapotranspiration. What will be more decisive for (evapo)transpiration of Canopy - higher temperature or higher CO2 levels?

Thank you!

Comment: Still not quite sure about this topic - some new article about it...
https://modernfarmer.com/2022/12/plants-have-mouths/